# Set up Stripe Line Size

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm building a report which I have to handle Stripe Lines.

I got to set up a Stripe Line vertically which's already done. However I have also to set up its size, is it possible?

I appreciate any suggestion.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Stripe Lines". Are you talking about a chart, cell colors on a tablix, etc.?

Comment: Stripe Lines of a Chart

Answer (score 0):

Under the Interval section of the StripeLine Properties window where you first set up the StripeLines, modify the StripWidth attribute to change the size of the Stripeline.

http://blog.jontav.com/post/7067899413/axis-striplines-in-ssrs-charts

Comment: Well, actually I'm not talking about its width but about its length/size/Height, I can't find where I can set up it!

Comment: Yes, weird, I know, but I believe the `StripeWidth` property is actually referring to the height because it is a horizontal line.

Since StripLines go all the way across the chart, there are only two other attributes to set: The y-axis location of the line, which is set by the `IntervalOffset` property, and the thickness/weight of the line, which I believe is set by the `StripeWidth` property.

Comment: None of them make it looks like the way I want it to be!
I am starting thinking there's no way to do it the way I want to!

Comment: Could you post an image of what you are trying to do? I'm not sure I understand, but I'm happy to keep trying :)